# Excel/Sheets - Adding the content of a row to the end of another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

So I'm still new-ish to data analysis on Excel and/or Sheets, and I'm trying to "merge" data.  Essentially, I have a few thousands rows, and I want every second row to be added to the first.  As an example:

1. A / B
2. C / D
3. E / F
4. G / H

should become

1. A / B / C / D
2. E / F / G / H

with / denoting a change of cell.  Is there a way to do this sheet-wide?  I was using Sheets at first, but can easily switch to Excel if it's a more advanced sorting option in there. I came here from a similar question trying to merge two documents sharing a column, using vlookup, but that doesn't seem to apply here. It seems like it's something basic, but I can't quite find anything like this, and can't quite word it properly either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding now that the items are in separate cells,

With Excel O365, you can use:

```
C2: =IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,INDEX($A:$B,SEQUENCE(2,,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*2+1),SEQUENCE(,2)))&"</s></t>","//s")),"")
```

and fill down as far as needed

[image]

In a more general sense, where you might want to vary the # of rows to join and the # of columns in the table, consider:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,INDEX($A:$B,SEQUENCE(rowsToJoin,,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*rowsToJoin+1),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($A:$B))))&"</s></t>","//s")),"")
```

Note in particular the parts:

```
SEQUENCE(rowsToJoin,,(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*rowsToJoin+1)
```

for the obvious.

And also that

```
INDEX($A:$B ...
```

and

```
SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($A:$B))
```

refer to the same columns range.

Finally, if there are empty cells that you want returned as blank cells in this joining, then change the `ignore_empty` argument of `TEXTJOIN` to `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!   I don't think Textjoin is necessary, as A, B, C and D would be different cells, and I don't need them all in one cell, just C and D added to the previous row as their own cells, but I think Sequence is a function going in the right direction, and I'll start looking into it.

Comment: @Pascal Didn't realize from your question that the entries were in different cells.

Comment: @Pascal OK, formula modified to account for the items being in separate cells.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!   I was fiddling around with Index and Sequence after your first reply, and managed to do most of what I wanted.  But this is even more elegant, and I'll definitely save it for posterity and my imminent next use of it.  Thanks a lot!